# Implementing my HbaseConnector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hbase

I would like to implement a HbaseConnector.
I'm actually reading the [guide](https://fr.hortonworks.com/blog/spark-hbase-dataframe-based-hbase-connector/) but there is a part that I don't understand and I can't find any information about it.
In the part 2 of the guide we can see the following code :

```
case class HBaseRecord(col0: String, col1: Boolean,col2: Double, col3: Float,col4: Int,       col5: Long, col6: Short, col7: String, col8: Byte)

object HBaseRecord {def apply(i: Int, t: String): HBaseRecord = { val s = s”””row${“%03d”.format(i)}”””       HBaseRecord(s, i % 2 == 0, i.toDouble, i.toFloat,  i, i.toLong, i.toShort,  s”String$i: $t”,      i.toByte) }}

val data = (0 to 255).map { i =>  HBaseRecord(i, “extra”)}
```

I do understand that they store the future column in the HbaseRecord case class but I don't understand the specific use of this line :

```
val s = s”””row${“%03d”.format(i)}”””
```

Could someone care to explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is used to generate row ids like `row001, row002` etc. which will populate column0 of your table. Try out simpler way with function

```
 def generate(i: Int): String = { s"""row${"%03d".format(i)}"""}
```